# Python: printing a statement, and asking for an input on same line

Tags: python

I am trying to print a string, that asks for an input from a user. The user enters the input on the same line. It is in python, here is what i have

```
print("Enter Series", end="")         
sympy.var("n")         
self.series=self._sanatize_series(input())         
print("Enter Limits", end="")         
self.lim=input()
```

Comment: input("this will be on the same line as the person is typeing")

Answer (score 1):

`input()` function can take a string parameter to print before reading.

So what you need to do is

```
sympy.var("n")         
self.series=self._sanatize_series(input("Enter Series: "))                
self.lim=input("Enter Limits: ")
```

Comment: _note_: When printing those messages, try ending them with a space or a colon (or both) because user's input will be written in the next position, making it hard to read sometimes